# PowerShell Parameter Sets allowing multiple choice if certain parameter set

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function in PowerShell where there is a particular Parameter Switch that then gives other choices, but these are only available for use if this parameter is used in conjunction with the main one. This will be for adding users to AD groups. I am still learning how ParameterSets work.

What I want is for something like this to be possible:

OK: (where 21 and 22 are the multiple choice switches

```
Set-UserAccess -user Username -Access1 -Access2 -Access21
Set-UserAccess -user Username -Access1 -Access2 -Access21 -Access22
Set-UserAccess -user Username -Access1 -Access2 -Access22
Set-UserAccess -user Username -Access2 -Access22
```

Not OK:

```
Set-UserAccess -user Username -Access1 -Access21
Set-UserAccess -user Username -Access1 -Access2
Set-UserAccess -Access21
```

Can you please advise how to create the Parameter Sets to allow this.

Basically what I have so far is (renamed to be generic for this question)

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Default')]
Param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
Position=0)][string[]]
$user,
[Parameter()][switch]$Access1,
[Parameter()][switch]$Access2,
[Parameter()][switch]$Access3,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Access4')][Switch]$Access4,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Access4')][Switch]$Access4Choice1,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Access4')][Switch]$Access4Choice2,
)
```

Please advise if any of this needs clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a parameter set for each multiple choice switch (Access4, 5 and 6). However, I would use a *string* as Parameter with a *ValidateSet*:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Default')]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
    Position=0)][string[]]
    $user,
    [switch]$Access1,
    [switch]$Access2,
    [switch]$Access3,
    [ValidateSet("Access4Choice1", "Access4Choice2", "Access4Choice3")]
    [string]$Access4
)
```

This will give your a choice of the parameter:
[image]

Comment: Just checking though, for that setup, can I choose multiple choices, or is that just a single choice? As that is required here.

Comment: You have to choice **one** of the strings within the validate set.

Comment: Or make it `[string[]]$Access4` (ISE doesn't show menu for 2nd parameter, but TAB Works)

Comment: Thanks Frode, I should have thought of that.And thanks Martin. Looks like that will work. I hadn't come across validated sets yet in my learning and research

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to take a look at [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters). Please consider to accept the answer using the green checkmark.